# Should I open a a MySQL Connection every request or always?

Tags: mysql, connection

Assuming I'll execute every 2 seconds a query, should I open the connection on every request or should I keep the connection alive until the application(server) stops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, establishing connections is unlikely to be a bottleneck for a mysql server (connection overhead is fairly low in mysql).  That having been said, reusing existing connections is often an appropriate approach, but it requires some careful considerations: if the database server is temporarily unavailable, the code must reconnect; if the server is replaced, it must reconnect (mysql implementations tend towards failover solutions rather than true high availability); if the application uses multiple connections to mysql, you must be sure not to cross your connections between users or sessions (active database, timezone, charset, and so on are sessions variables, essentially tied to a connection).  If you're not up to the task of making your reusable connection reliable in these and other edge cases, creating a new connection every 2 seconds may provide this durability for free.

In short, there can be less-than-obvious benefits to short lived connections.  I would not bother to add intelligence around maintaining a persistent connection unless you have reason to believe it will actually make a meaningful difference in your case (eg benchmarks).

Comment: Assuming the projects grows, and I'll have about 200 requests every second?

Comment: I'm not following.  Are you executing the query every 2 seconds, or for every connection, which on average is happening every two seconds currently?  Those are very different things.

Comment: In the first example I'm executing 1 query every 2 seconds. In the second example(comment above) I'm executing 200 querys a second.

Comment: Then I guess the question is, what is a 'request' vs a 'query'.  Typically the life of a short lived connection sees a connection, a few sessions parameters set ( choose database, etc ) and then a _number_ of queries execute before the connection is closed.  If the 200 queries are all part of the same connection, it doesn't really matter.  IF each query is a different connection, that's starting to sound like a lot of concurrent new connections, in which case you might want to think about reusing connections.  Just make sure to consider durability!